# Can't send careers invitations

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Last week, I received 5 SO Careers 2.0 invitations to give out.  I gave out one on Sunday, but now, when I came back to give another one, I received a 500 error (with a picture of Statler and Waldorf).

What's going on?  Are my invitations safe?  I promised a friend I would send him one and he's waiting.

Answer (score 1):

This should be resolved, and your invitations safe. Please have another look.